# Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin - how to deinitialize it?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, tablednd

I am using Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin (http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/).

I have a button that initializes sorting. But, after sorting is done, I want to deinitialize it, so user can continue with other tasks. How to deinitialise sort, or disable it, after initialization?

Btw, initialization code is:

```
$('table.listing').tableDnD({
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
    ... serialization of data and ajax post here...
    }                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `function`

```
 unbind().
```

See this

```
 $("table").unbind("mousedown");
```

Hope this helps.